# JavaScript killing a process

Tags: javascript, wsh

I am writing using JavaScript. I have a PID of a process. How do I kill it?
You can terminate by a name using [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), How can you do it using PID?

UPDATE: The platform is Windows.

Comment: kill -9 PID ???  you must be talking about a Rhino VM I guess.

Comment: i doubt any system is going to let Javascript do root level commands!

Comment: You need to tell us in what environment this is running. Is it JScript on the Windows Script Host, for example?

Comment: @PurplePilot: Windows shell scripts can be written in Javascript (JScript).  Who voted that this belongs on superuser? it's clearly a programming question.

Comment: @Andy E Thanks didn't know. I think i should have qualified it being from/in a browser, which should be sandboxed. If you really tried you could run anything from anywhere ;-)

Comment: @PurplePilot Another tidbit is that you can compile a JS file to an .exe using a compiler included in .NET (and you have access to regular .NET libraries).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're coding for either Windows Script Host or a Windows Desktop Gadget.  If it is, I would use `WScript.Shell` and its `Exec` method along with the command line taskkill (Win XP Pro, Win Vista & Win 7 only):

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("taskkill /pid 1234");
```

If you really want to do it with WMI something like the following works fine for me (thanks @Helen for the improvements):

```
function killPID (pid) {
  GetObject("winmgmts:").Get("Win32_Process.Handle='" + pid + "'").Terminate();
}
```

Comment: I need it n windo 2000 and windows server 2003

Comment: Why not use `ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Handle='" + pid + "'")` instead of `InstancesOf` + `if`?

Comment: @Helen, you could do that, you'd still have to enumerate them though.  It is a better method, I'll swap it with my code.

Comment: On second thought, it can be even simpler - just `Get("Win32_Process.Handle='" + pid + "'")`, and no enumeration at all. (That's because `Handle` is a key property that uniquely identifies `Win32_Process` objects.)

Comment: @Helen: I tried that, it didn't work (threw an error actually).  The original code I pasted here was part of a script that listed all running processes (like `tasklist`, but for something else), I didn't want to change it too much in case I broke it; my WMI expertise isn't that great beyond writing, enumerating and deleting registry keys :-)

Comment: Sorry, I might've been unclear. The function body (if written in one line) can be `GetObject("winmgmts:").Get("Win32_Process.Handle='" + pid + "'").Terminate()`, and I can confirm this code works on Windows XP (provided that the process with the specified ID is found; otherwise an exception is thrown that can be caught with `try`...`catch`). And it should work on Windows 2000+, in fact.

Comment: @Helen: just came back around to this answer to check something and your one-liner worked fine.  I forgot about it before, but I've updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 2000 you will need to install the **Windows Support Tools** and then use the `Kill` command from the shell as Andy E described in his answer..

Reference: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5031568.html